# replace all values in a string using preg_replace with callback

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm not sure if this can be done with preg_replace, but this is what I have so far

```
$string='
<div class="row">
  <section> [1] </section>
  <section> [2] </section>
  <section> [5] </section>
</div>';


function searchArray($myarray, $id) {
    foreach ($myarray as $item) {
        if ($item[$id] == $id)
            return $item['name'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

So I need to run $string through preg_replace where each var between [] will correspond to an actual id stored in multidimensional array. This is where function searchArray() comes in. Basically runs string, replace [] with actual id's and print name of the field. All this needs to happen when I submit form in one pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this as an alternative to *preg_replace*...

```
$arr = array('apple', 'pear', 'bananna', 'orange', 'grapefruit', 'pineapple');
$string='
<div class="row">
  <section> [1] </section>
  <section> [2] </section>
  <section> [5] </section>
</div>';

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $string = str_replace($key, $value, $string);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$arr = array(
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'matthew'),
    array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'william'),
    array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'john'),
    array('id'=>4, 'name'=>'george'),
    array('id'=>5, 'name'=>'henry'),
    array('id'=>6, 'name'=>'jason')
);
$string='
<div class="row">
  <section> [1] </section>
  <section> [2] </section>
  <section> [4] </section>
    <section> [1] </section>
</div>';
foreach($arr as $key => $subArr){
    $string = str_replace("[".$subArr['id']."]", $subArr['name'], $string);
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work. It's multidimensional array, and each [] needs to match actual id, than to be replaced with corresponding name value

Comment: So what ID's are you looking to replace? If it's multi-dimensional then it will be in the form `[][]` ??

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with some more code which (if I now understand what you were aiming to do) should be what you're looking for.